# How create Custom HTML Helper in Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i am new in MVC and trying to write a sample html helper like this way
here is my html helper code.

```
namespace MvcPractise.Extension
{
    public static class LabelHelper
    {
        public static string Label(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
        {
            return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);

        }
    }
}
```

i use it as follows in my view like

```
@using MvcPractise.Extension.LabelHelper
@model MvcPractise.Models.EmployeeModel
```

at the top of the view i declare or refere the namespace and class name like above

and use it like `@Html.Label("firstName", "First Name:")`

but when i debug the code the my extension method is not getting hit. i could understand that i am doing something wrong but could not figure out. so please help. thanks

Comment: you're using `@Html.Label("firstName", "First Name:")` but your method is `MLabel`

Comment: sorry later i change that name.

Comment: tell me this line is ok in view declared at top @using MvcPractise.Extension.LabelHelper ?

Comment: Do u get .Label in `intellisense`?

Comment: yes but that point to in-built label() method not mine one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you, I would not name it as the original name from the Html Helper. I would try something like:

```
public static string CustomLabel(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, string text)
{
   return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);
}
```

After it, just include the namespace (not the entire path to the class), for sample:

```
@using MvcPractise.Extension
```

And as the extension method, use it on `Html` property:

```
@Html.CustomLabel("firstName", "First Name:")
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Label` is a built in helper, you need to try another name, like `@Html.LabelEx`

Rename your extension method to something, that is not in the standard library! And it should work!

Answer (score -1):

Try as follows it may be because of ambuiguity of `Label`
and you are using the label of `Html` helper and not `custom` helper

`@using MvcPractise.Extension`

`@LabelHelper.LabelCustom("firstName", "First Name:")`

Your extension method:

```
    public static string LabelCustom(string target, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
  public static string Label(string target, string text)
    {
        return String.Format("<label for='{0}'>{1}</label>", target, text);

    }
```

Comment: Please try to explain your answer in at least a short sentence and try to refrain from just posting a single line of code.